# Multiple Swipe down Gestures in one fragment

Tags: android, kotlin

//this is my code for SwipeDown on a image view, de image disappears. This is working fine
//But on the same fragment i want another swipe down on a recyclerview (refresh). How can i do that?. I tried a when statement but its not working.

```
private fun swipeDown() {
  
    imageOne.isVisible = false. // so this is for swipe 1
    RecyclerviewAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()  // this is for swipe 2
```

Answer (score 0):

Is the initial image inside the RecyclerView?  If so, you might have overlapping gestures.  Perhaps you could try passing down a reference to the View object that is getting the gesture action as a parameter to your method to better discriminate between the two different Views.
E.g.

```
private fun swipeDown(view: View) {
    when (view) {
        myTextView -> imageOne.isVisible = false. // so this is for swipe 1
        myRecyclerView -> RecyclerviewAdapter?.notifyDataSetChanged()  // this is for swipe 2
    }
```

Also, have you considered using [androidx.swiperefreshlayout](https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/swiperefreshlayout) as part of your RecyclerView layout? I bet it could make your life a lot easier!

Comment: no the image is not in the recyclerview. Its a separate imageView, but in the same fragment. I thought maybe that i could pass in a View in de swipe() function, but thats not working.

Comment: I think that androidx library should help on it's own, at least for the RecyclerView side and keep that method for your TextView. 
Otherwise, I would recommend using a two separate functions for these two very different actions for the sake of Single-responsibility SOLID principle anyway.

Comment: Yep your right, i implemented the swiperefreshlayout, works fine. Tx

Comment: Glad to hear it worked @sander! I'd love it if you could accept my answer if you're satisfied. Happy hacking!